# How to Debug LWC components from Community

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, b2b-commerce

I want to debug my LWC component from within a Community. However the Debug mode dosen't affect the minification of the JS in the as a Community User, only in the Builder ( that dosen't work for my purposes ).
I know I can debug from outside, creating a Lightning Page, however I'm in a B2B Commerce Store Community and my component is supposed to be communicating with a std B2B component, so I wanted to debug the integration between them.

Comment: Did you find a way to debug ?

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to debug the JavaScript, I would recommend using the Chrome dev console. You can pretty print the JS so it is easier to read and you can add your own breakpoints right there in the console.

I work on LWC community components all of the time and my process is to test as a user and open the Chrome dev tools to analyze any issues. These tools are far more robust than the Lightning debug tools provided by SFDC.

Here is a primer on the above: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Best of luck to you!

Comment: LWC are minified so you cannot simply debug using dev console. You can enable debug mode to not minify the LWC but it does not seems to work for community users.

Comment: @RaphaelD in Community (Experience Cloud) you are able to debug the components, when previewing as a logged in or guest user, open the console, go to Sources ==> root ==> C ==> <your LWC component> ==> then at the top of the minified view, click pretty print and presto :)

Comment: yes it it worked for me but you to enable debug mode for the specific user unless the pretty print will still display minify code

Comment: @RaphaelD I believe that it should be the same as a specific user.... you could always put some console logs in your JS code if you are in sandbox. Sometimes those are just the easiest to use, esp. with JSON.stringify() for datasets :)